# MicroSD Card not being read by usb adapter on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, usb, sd-card, adapter, micro-sd-card

I have a MicroSD card which I plugged into a USB sd card reader. Looks like this:

[image: Adapter]

The MicroSD card goes all the way in (left it out to show where it goes). When I insert the USB in my Macbook Pro, nothing happens. The laptop doesn't read it, it doesn't show up in Disk Utility either. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: try a different card, eliminate the adaptor as the issue. Make sure the contacts are clean.

Comment: I've tried 4 different cards. They work with the adapter on another computer. This led me to believe I was missing drivers, though I can't find any drivers SanDisk drivers on their site (get a 404 page).

Comment: shouldn't need drivers, looks like a pretty standard piece of kit. Tried it in another port? Something else in that port?

Comment: Then I'm not sure what could be wrong. When I plug in a normal sized SD Card into the MBP SD slot, it works or when I plug in USB's into their slots, they work as well. So I know there's nothing wrong internally.

EDIT: Yes, I did try another port.

Comment: Has it ever worked with that machine? last possibility is it just 'doesn't like it' for some arcane reason.. & as to why that may be, I'm stumped

Comment: This is the first time I'm trying it on here.